# Unable to read Sharepoint List?

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

We have two lists in SharePoint which are being used as Master / Meta information with files. I want to list contents of these list using C# but am unable to do it.

C# code is throwing an error and asking for a SharePoint.intl file. I am unable to locate this file. Can anyone suggest, how to read SharePoint list in C#?

Sample code is below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SPSite oSpSite = new SPSite("https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MHLanding/");

        SPWeb oSPWeb = oSpSite.OpenWeb();

        SPList oSpList = oSPWeb.Lists["PermissionMatrix"];

        SPListItemCollection oSpListCln = oSpList.Items;

        foreach (SPListItem item in oSpListCln)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["SiteWorker"] + "\n");
        }

    }
```

Comment: It fails at build or runtime? If is runtime, what line? 
I don't see the authentication code in your sample. Are you posting just part of the code?
Also, you should be disposing the spsite and spweb variables as best practice code.

Comment: Fails at Build. Can you share code snipt which reads a list of sharepoint. No sure if missing something (reference to DLL or ???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked following solution:

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the
// server running SharePoint.
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://{site_url}");

// Assume the web has a list named "Announcements".
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

// This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies     Scope="RecursiveAll"
 // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in.
 CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
 ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query);

// Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query).
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{
  // We have all the list item data. For example, Title.
  label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + listItem["Title"];
}
```